# Serialize form with Froala Editor in "Code View" mode not working properly

Tags: froala

I have form with Froala editor and I'm submitting data trough AJAX call.

Before sending ajax call form is serialized using JQuery

`var serializedForm = $('form').serialize();`

When I am in Code View mode and submit `serializedForm` does not set new value.

When I exit Code View mode and submit `serializedForm` has new value

If I submit form in traditional way (just for test purpose) correct value is passed in both 'WYSWYG' and 'Code View' mode.

I presume there is some event handler that triggers every time form is submitted that is not being triggered when form is serialized but I cannot find anything online.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out there is event handler for form submit event in CodeView plugin that does its *magic*.

In my case I had to  emulate `form.submit` by loading emulator and triggering event manually.

```
var editor = $('#editor')[0]['data-froala.editor'];
editor.events.trigger('form.submit');

var serializedForm = $('form').serialize();
```

Hope it helps someone